# Panning Google Maps Static Image API

Tags: math, google-maps-static-api

I am trying to implement panning using Google's static image api, but don't really know where to start.

Given:
lat,lng = 36.059534,-94.171257 of the center of the image
zoom level = 19
image size = 400x400

Question:
How do I calculate the lat,lng of the upper left and lower right corners of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have searched better.  This is [exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763917/google-static-maps-move-maps-with-a-finger) what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Google uses the same numbering format as OpenStreetMap and in their wiki there is a very detailed description about the tile numbering scheme and how to use it. If it works with OSM you simply have to change the url a bit.

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames